# Shoping cart page fee value return 0

Tags: magento2, database, cart, shopping-cart

I want to retrieve database value in cart page but it shows **0**.
Please review my code.

```
app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee.php
```

```
/**
 * Collect grand total address amount
 *
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
 * @return $this
 */
protected $quoteValidator = null;

protected $rewardspointCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteValidator $quoteValidator,
        \Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Fee\CollectionFactory $rewardspointCollectionFactory
        ) {
    $this->quoteValidator = $quoteValidator;
    $this->rewardspointCollectionFactory = $rewardspointCollectionFactory;
}

public function collect(
\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
) {
    parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);


    $exist_amount = 0; //$quote->getFee(); 
    $fee = 10; //Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
    $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;

    $total->setTotalAmount('fee', $balance);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('fee', $balance);

    $total->setFee($balance);
    $total->setBaseFee($balance);

    $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $balance);
    $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() + $balance);


    return $this;
}

protected function clearValues(Address\Total $total) {
    $total->setTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
    $total->setTotalAmount('tax', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', 0);
    $total->setTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setSubtotalInclTax(0);
    $total->setBaseSubtotalInclTax(0);
}

/**
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
 * @param Address\Total $total
 * @return array|null
 */

/**
 * Assign subtotal amount and label to address object
 *
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
 * @param Address\Total $total
 * @return array
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total) {


    $rewardspointCollection = $this->rewardspointCollectionFactory->create();
    $customerId = $quote->getCustomerId();
    $rewardspointCollection->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('dukaaniatest_id',$customerId);
    if(count($rewardspointCollection) > 1){
       $firstItem =  $rewardspointCollection->geFirstItem();
       return [
        'code' => 'fee',
        'title' => $firstItem->getData('title'),
        'value' => $firstItem->getData('author')
    ];
    }else{
        return [
        'code' => 'fee',
        'title' => 'Fee',
        'value' => 'title',
    ];
    }



}

/**
 * Get Subtotal label
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 */
public function getLabel() {
    return __('Fee');
}

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to retrieve from database ? which database ? wich method are you using ?

Comment: Please see the link that I asked a question here my complete code
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244677/custom-table-data-fetch-and-show-in-cart-page

Answer (score 0):

You need `Model`, `Resource Model`, `Resource Model Collection`

1. > app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee.php
2. > app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/ResourceModel/Fee.php
3. > app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/ResourceModel/Fee/Collection.php

Comment: i have all 3 classes or pages 
i shared you a link in that all function

Comment: please see that links all classes or pages define in it
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244677/custom-table-data-fetch-and-show-in-cart-page

Comment: You already gave it to me and I answered you

Comment: so what i need now ????? i created all those files

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/244695/48355

Comment: facing this error Fatal error: Class Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total\Fee contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface::getIdentities) in /home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee.php on line 7