# custom table data fetch and show in cart page

Tags: magento2, database, cart

I want to fetch custom table data and show on cart page.
Don't need to do from customer id (session).
Please review my code and give me a solution.

Here's my code:

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee.php

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
class Fee extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal {

/**
 * Collect grand total address amount
 *
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
 * @return $this
 */
protected $quoteValidator = null;

protected $rewardspointCollectionFactory;
 protected $customerSession;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteValidator $quoteValidator,
        \Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Fee\CollectionFactory $rewardspointCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
        ) {
    $this->quoteValidator = $quoteValidator;
    $this->rewardspointCollectionFactory = $rewardspointCollectionFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;

}

public function collect(
\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
) {
    parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);


    $exist_amount = 0; //$quote->getFee(); 
    $fee = 10; //Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
    $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;

    $total->setTotalAmount('fee', $balance);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('fee', $balance);

    $total->setFee($balance);
    $total->setBaseFee($balance);

    $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $balance);
    $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() + $balance);


    return $this;
}

protected function clearValues(Address\Total $total) {
    $total->setTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
    $total->setTotalAmount('tax', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', 0);
    $total->setTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setSubtotalInclTax(0);
    $total->setBaseSubtotalInclTax(0);
}
```

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
 * @param Address\Total $total
 * @return array|null
 */

/**
 * Assign subtotal amount and label to address object
 *
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
 * @param Address\Total $total
 * @return array
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */





public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total) {
$rewardspointCollection = $this->rewardspointCollectionFactory->create();
$customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
//$customerId = $quote->getCustomerId();

$rewardspointCollection->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('dukaaniatest_id',$customerId);
if(empty($rewardspointCollection)){
   return "Data not found";
} else {
    return 'your collection data';
}
}
/**
 * Get Subtotal label
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 */
public function getLabel() {
    return __('Fee');
}

}
```

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/ResourceModel/Fee/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Fee;


class Collection extends 
\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
public function _construct()
{
    $this->_init(
        \Sugarcode\Test\Model\Fee::class,
        \Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Fee::class
    );
}

}
```

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/ResourceModel/Fee.php

```
<?php
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel;


class Fee extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{

/**
 * Resource initialization
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('mr_dukaaniatest', 'dukaaniatest_id');
}
}
```

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Fee.php

```
<?php
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model;


class Fee extends  \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
public function _construct()
{
    $this->_init(\Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Fee::class);
}

}
```

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Block/Sales/Order/Fee.php

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

/**
* Tax totals modification block. Can be used just as subblock of 
\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals
*/
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Block\Sales\Order;



class Fee extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
/**
 * Tax configuration model
 *
 * @var \Magento\Tax\Model\Config
 */
protected $_config;

/**
 * @var Order
 */
protected $_order;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject
 */
protected $_source;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Tax\Model\Config $taxConfig
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Tax\Model\Config $taxConfig,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_config = $taxConfig;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Check if we nedd display full tax total info
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function displayFullSummary()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get data (totals) source model
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\DataObject
 */
public function getSource()
{
    return $this->_source;
} 
public function getStore()
{
    return $this->_order->getStore();
}

  /**
 * @return Order
 */
public function getOrder()
{
    return $this->_order;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getLabelProperties()
{
    return $this->getParentBlock()->getLabelProperties();
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getValueProperties()
{
    return $this->getParentBlock()->getValueProperties();
}

/**
 * Initialize all order totals relates with tax
 *
 * @return \Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax
 */
 public function initTotals()
{

    $parent = $this->getParentBlock();
    $this->_order = $parent->getOrder();
    $this->_source = $parent->getSource();

    $store = $this->getStore();

    $fee = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'fee',
                'strong' => false,
                'value' => 120,
                //'value' => $this->_source->getFee(),
                'label' => __('Fee'),
            ]
        );

        $parent->addTotal($fee, 'fee');
       // $this->_addTax('grand_total');


        return $this;

       }

    }
```

Comment: What is your database Name  and `primary_key` please ?

Comment: mr_dukaaniatest database name

Comment: primary_key please

Comment: dukaaniatest_id

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee.php

```
<?php
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total;
class Fee extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    const CACHE_TAG = 'mr_dukaaniatest';

    protected $_cacheTag = 'mr_dukaaniatest';

    protected $_eventPrefix = 'mr_dukaaniatest';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Fee.php');
    }

    ...
```

> app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/ResourceModel/Fee.php

```
<?php
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel;


class Fee extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('mr_dukaaniatest', 'dukaaniatest_id');
    }

}
```

> app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/ResourceModel/Fee/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Fee;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'dukaaniatest_id';
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'mr_dukaaniatest_collection';
    protected $_eventObject = 'fee_collection';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total\Fee', 'Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Fee');
    }

}
```

Now you can get your **data values** from your database where you want to retrieve them by injecting the `modelFactory` dependency like this:

```
protected $_feeFactory;

public function __construct(
        \Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total\FeeFactory $feeFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context)
        $this->_feeFactory = $feeFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $fee = $this->_feeFactory->create();
        $collection = $fee->getCollection();
        foreach($collection as $item){
            \Zend_Debug::dump($item->getData());
        }
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: where i put this modelFactory  class ?

Comment: In your constructor `__construct` everything is explained

Comment: so basically i need to iverwrite this class with your code
/home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee.php

Comment: facing this error
Fatal error: Class Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total\Fee contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface::getIdentities) in /home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee.php on line 7